# Issue with PHP Excel sheet for showing encrypted string instead of number I used

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpexcel, xls

I am using PHP Excel to make sheet in XLS format. There is an cell which is used to hold a number let's suppose 34567898 but when the sheet generates/downloaded it will became like 234E876 (like encrypted number). When I double-click on the sheet it converted into number same as I want.

I heard about to make cell format in text, so I change the format to text by this function

```
($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
->getStyle('C1')
->getNumberFormat()
->setFormatCode(
    \PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT
);)
```

but it not works although when I check the format in sheet it is in text means function works but cell still showing the string 234E876.

Comment: Provide actuals (rather than play "lets suppose").... a number `34567898` is __never___ going to give `234E876`.... conceivably it could give `3.46E+07` or similar, which is called "scientific notation", but it does not change numbers to completely different numbers

Comment: And `FORMAT_TEXT` is meaningless for numbers, it's for string values.... numbers should be formatted as numbers

Comment: [Text or number converted to unintended number format in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214233)